# Animate button on Show or Hide in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a button in ListView which shows and hides based on the button press in ActionBar.

The button is in `GetView` function like this

```
ImageButton btnDel = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btn_row_del);
if(_isEdit)
{
    if(btnDel.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
    {
        btnDel.Animate().TranslationX(0).SetDuration(2000);
    }                
}
else
{
    if (btnDel.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
    {
        btnDel.Animate().TranslationX(btnDel.Width).SetDuration(2000);
    }
}
```

But the animation doesn't seem to be working.
How can I animate a button inside of a list view.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is not working?

Comment: The animation, it's not working, it's not animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might set the button gone or visible immediately when you press your action bar.

You need to set the button gone or visible when animation end by adding the following call back listener:

```
    private void Bt2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt1.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            AlphaAnimation disappearAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            disappearAnimation.Duration = 2000;
            bt1.StartAnimation(disappearAnimation);
            disappearAnimation.AnimationStart += DisappearAnimation_AnimationStart;
            disappearAnimation.AnimationEnd += DisappearAnimation_AnimationEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            AlphaAnimation disappearAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            disappearAnimation.Duration = 2000;
            bt1.StartAnimation(disappearAnimation);
            disappearAnimation.AnimationStart += DisappearAnimation_AnimationStart;
            disappearAnimation.AnimationEnd += DisappearAnimation_AnimationEnd;
        }
    }

    private void DisappearAnimation_AnimationStart(object sender, Animation.AnimationStartEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt1.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            bt1.Animate().TranslationX(bt1.Width).SetDuration(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            bt1.Animate().TranslationX(0).SetDuration(2000);
        }
    }

    private void DisappearAnimation_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bt1.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            bt1.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
        else
        {
            bt1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
```

screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Start()` to your animation:

`btnDel.Animate().TranslationX(btnDel.Width).SetDuration(2000).Start();`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
How can I get the animation to be hidden at the start then animate into visibility and vice versa?